# How to increase the darkness of the text when printing in Win Form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printdocument, drawingbrush

I'm trying to print a document in C#. However, the Black color of the text isn't good. It's dim. How can I adjust the quality of the text color in order to make it darker and clearer? 
Here is my code :

```
 Font font = new Font("Courier New", 18);
 SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

 graphic.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"), font, brush,10,10);
```

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: It doesn't get more black than `Black`. Get a better printer or change your font with a more *meaty* font as suggested by @SteveFreg.

Comment: Check the default settings in your printer driver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **Courier New**, use another font like **Arial Black** or **Copperplate Gothic Bold**

Answer (score 1):

```
//for more clearer rendering of text use
graphic.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

//for darker font use BOLD font style
Font font = new Font("Courier New", 18,FontStyle.Bold);
```

So your code becomes

```
 graphic.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
 Font font = new Font("Courier New", 18,FontStyle.Bold);
 SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

 graphic.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"), font, brush,10,10);
```